# Updating already uploaded image in my Laravel crud

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, backend, laravel-8

Getting this error after updating the image.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string

This is the before code. If I **dd();** this code I get the file name with the extension but it's a string. So I cannot get the original extension.

```
        $image = $request->warrantyUpload;
        $destination =  public_path('/uploads/');
        $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFilename = "img_".rand(111111,999999);
        $image->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
        $image->warrantyUpload = $mainFilename.".".$ext;


        $data->warrantyUplaod = $image->warrantyUpload;
        $data->save();
```

I changed my code to this. If I **dd();** this code I don't get anything. Just a **NULL**.

```
        $image = $request->file('warrantyUpload');
        $destination =  public_path('/uploads/');
        $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $mainFilename = "img_".rand(111111,999999);
        $image->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
        $image->warrantyUpload = $mainFilename.".".$ext;

        $data->warrantyUplaod = $image->warrantyUpload;
        $data->save();
```

And the error now is :

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

I have also tried **'PATCH'** and **'PUT'** both methods.

This is View Code :

```
<form action="{{ route('assets.update', $data->_id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
@method('PATCH')

<div class="form-group col-10">
     <label for="warrantyUpload">Warranty Card:</label>
     <input type="file" class="form-control p-1" required="required" value="{{$data->warrantyUpload}}" name="warrantyUpload">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-10">
<button type="subumit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the **dd($request->all());**

[DD($request->all());](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sHt4.png)

Comment: can you add the form code in the view?

Comment: I have added code for this part only. This is with the patch method. I have tried put too

Comment: are you getting image in request ? dd($request->all()); post this in your question

Comment: Yes, But only as a string not a file